# TensorFlow get stuck after use concatenate layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, concatenation, google-colaboratory

I have the next model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (10, 300, 1))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (24, ))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu')(input1)

x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (2,2), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, input2])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input1,input2], outputs = output)

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
          loss ='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics = ['acc'])

history = model.fit([X_train, X_features], y_train,
                batch_size=64,
                epochs=100)
```

But when I try to fit it, get stuck and only appears Epoch 1/100 and nothing more happens even if i let it run for hours. But when I remove the concatenate layer, everything go well. I'm using Google colab. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share the code about X_train, X_features information to reproduce your issue so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Actually yes, I don't know why but I change from Google Colab to a local Jupyter Notebook and the problem get solve. Never stuck again. I'm not sure but maybe was a problem with the resource of Colab.